# Handle initials in Postgresql

Tags: regex, postgresql, regex-lookarounds

I'd like to keep together initials (max two letters) when there are punctuation or spaces in between.

I have the following snippet to tackle almost everything, but I am having issues in keeping together initials that are separated by punctuation and space. For instance, this is working on regular regex, but not in postgresql:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('R Z ELEMENTARY SCHOOL', 
                      '(\b[A-Za-z]{1,2}\b)\s+\W*(?=[a-zA-Z]{1,2}\b)', 
                      '\1')
```

The outcome should be "RZ ELEMENTARY SCHOOL". Other examples will include:

```
A & D ALTERNATIVE EDUCATION
J. & H. KNOWLEDGE DEVELOPMENT
A. - Z. EVOLUTION IN EDUCATION
```

The transformation should be as follows:

```
AD ALTERNATIVE EDUCATION
JH KNOWLEDGE DEVELOPMENT
AZ EVOLUTION IN EDUCATION
```

How to achieve this in Postgresql?

Thanks

Comment: Well, it does not actually work even in a "normal" regex. Are there always just two initials? Are they always at the start of string?

Comment: Or, is `JH. KNOWLEDGE DEVELOPMENT` and `AZ. EVOLUTION IN EDUCATION` output OK?

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor Would be without the period at the end of the initials

Comment: Will there be exactly two or can there be more? Is the number of initials fixed to some amount?

Comment: There is no fixed amount of letters. The initials can be as "Y-M-C-A INSTITUTION" or "N.A.S.D. & AQ EXAMPLE" should be transformed to YMCA INSTITUTION and NASDAQ EXAMPLE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on your current regex, I can recommend

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
    REGEXP_REPLACE('J. & H. KNOWLEDGE DEVELOPMENT', '\m([[:alpha:]]{1,2})\M\s*\W*(?=[[:alpha:]]{1,2}\M)', '\1'),
    '^([[:alpha:]]+)\W+',
    '\1 '
)
```

See the [online demo](https://rextester.com/TGBJH47936), yielding

```
    regexp_replace
1   JH KNOWLEDGE DEVELOPMENT
```

It is a two step solution. The first regex matches

- `\m([[:alpha:]]{1,2})\M` - a whole one or two letter words captured into Group 1 (`\m` is a leading word boundar, and `\M` is a trailing word boundary)
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\W*` - zero or more non-word chars
- `(?=[[:alpha:]]{1,2}\M)` - a positive lookahead that requires a whole one or two letter word immediately to the right of the current position.

The match is replaced with the contents of Group 1 (`\1`).

The second regex matches a letter word at the start of the string and replaces all non-word chars after it with a space.

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor Stribizew, the solution works great except for some cases. How could I get the abbreviations in `--H.G.E. PUBLIC EDUCATION
--A S G FULL TIME`

Comment: @JuanPerez I do not understand if the string above is a single record or two separate ones (https://regex101.com/r/Jw8lpF/1).

Comment: Sorry, they are two different records.